# mean distance between three point

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

I have a question that I would like your help solving.

Let say I have three different points $a,b,c$ and a radius $r$.

Let say the $A,B,C$ are the circles with the centers $a,b,c$ respectively and with radius $r$.
Now, I know that the point $b$ lays in the circle $A$, and the point $c$ lies in the circle $B$ **but** not $A$ (meaning that $c$ is in the lune created by circles $A$ and $B$, $c$ is in $B\setminus A$).
I want to calculate the mean distance between points $a$ and $c$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, we can help better if you show us what have you tried

Comment: What distribution you assume? Binary?

Comment: Normal distribution